# What's the proper way to forward audio from i386 executables that use ALSA to an x64 pulse server?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio, ubuntu-13.04

I'm running Kubuntu Raring x64, and I had a program that I was unable to compile under my 64-bit environment but there was an already compiled version (32-bit) available for download (specifically OpenITG).

After fiddling a bit with i386 libraries, I have the program running, but it's completely bypassing my pulseaudio server and taking control over ALSA entirely, blocking any other ALSA application from playing sound (causing things like flash to hang in my browser), and attempting to make it play nice with padsp gives the following nonfatal error.

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

Does anyone know the proper way to make this work?

Comment: Sad to see how old this is without a useful response, as I fear it's the same issue causing me woes with wine on Slackware64 14.1.  If you solved the matter in the last 10 months quietly, I'd love to hear the answer :-).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been able to fix this issue.

Comment: I did end up solving my issue.  Do you have 32 bit versions of pulseaudio and its dependencies installed?  And what's your .asoundrc or /etc/asound.conf look like?  My particular issue (question, stumbling around to figure it out, and eventual answer) is all [here](https://superuser.com/questions/797748/how-can-i-get-wine-to-support-outputting-to-pulseaudio-through-alsa-compatibili) if you're interested in taking a look.  I know Ubuntu and Slackware handle 32 bit compatibility a bit differently, but it may give you a few ideas.